# Notation parse rule does parse when it acts as a argument

Tags: control-systems, custom-notation

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html

> Notation[boxes ⟹ expr]    set boxes to be parsed to expr

I want a simplified notation for entering a TransferFunctionModel by Notaton.
But the Notation rule doesn't parse expression when the expression as one argument

is there any missing step?

[image]

I found the subtle problem by the `FullForm`

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you have identified your problem, but it would be better to post this as an answer, rather than changing the question.

Comment: @mikao,your answer is really one solution, however, I am determined to figure out the missing step of the way by `Notation`. You see `In[73]` successfully outputs a `TransferFunctionModel` after `Shift + Enter`, how to do this when this expression acts as the argument of `BodePolt`

Comment: I think you can put my function `totf` inside the RHS of `Notation`

Comment: I have had a try, it turned out the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what problem you are trying to solve here.  Normally, you would use such a call to the `Notation` package to introduce a pretty way of displaying some Mathematica object.  Here that is unnecessary as Mathematica does what you are asking automatically.

I infer that you are wanting a simplified notation for entering a `TransferFunctionModel`.  One way to do this is with

```
totf[expr_] := TransferFunctionModel[{{expr}}, First[Cases[expr, _Symbol, ∞]]]
```

This lets you do

[image]

In my opinion, the `Notation` package is probably best left to advanced users of Mathematica.  I would advise you to learn the basics first.  However, you can use the function `totf` to define a notation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the missing step is

> s = $CellContext`s

[image]

Comment: I've extended my answer to provide a better (in my opinion) solution

Comment: Perfect, I missed the this method. I just put the definiton of `totf` at inside the RHS of Notation, and this underwent the same mistake.  It turned out that the function name not the definiton should be there.

Comment: I think the problem is that if you use the definition for `totf` it is evaluated immediately.  As it doesn't contain the transfer function (at that point) it won't work.

Using `:=` in the definition of `totf` delays evaluation until a value is given for the transfer function.